# set html form elements using php?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with some fields like text , select etc.
I need to set the variable using php. I have some values in the session which is to be put in the text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say where your variables come from, but if you need to move them from one page to another, you will have to use `session_start();` at the beginning of each php page.

Answer (score 3):

you can put like this,

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $SESSION['variable_name'];?>" />
<textarea><?php echo $SESSION['variable_name'];?></textarea>
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Thanks! :D